# HTML all text between two <div> tags vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, linq

i'm working on a program which is converting an HTML text into articles which can be put inside a database.

The html looks like this:

```
<HTML>
    <div class="article" code="article-0001" title="title">
        <p>blablabla</p>
        <p>blablablablablabblablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="article" code="article-0002" title="title2">
        <p>blablabla</p>
        <p>blablablablablabblablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</HTML>
```

I know how to read out the attributes inside the `<div>` tags.
i want to read out all information between the starting and ending of the div tag.

The text between the div tags is HTML made up text which i want to store inside my database. This means all HTML tags inside it (like the `<p>` & `</p>` you see below) have to be read.

How can i read all this text in VB.net
At the moment i'm using `Xdocument` & `Xelement` combined with linq but i can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: I've had more success parsing out HTML just treating it as text and using string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Xml.XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) makes this quite easy, if you want the text inside the div tags without the HTML markup use [.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innertext.aspx), i.e.

```
Dim doc = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(xml)
Dim divs = doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes
For Each div As System.Xml.XmlNode In divs
    Console.WriteLine(div.InnerText)
Next
```

If you want to keep the markup then use [.InnerXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e.:

```
Dim doc = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(xml)
Dim divs = doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes
For Each div As System.Xml.XmlNode In divs
    Console.WriteLine(div.InnerXml.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: Thanks the innerText and innerXml part was what i needed. i fixed it now creating an XmlReader of the element and using it's ReadInnerXml function

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck manipulating html with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  You can also find it on nuget.

One potential problem using `Xdocument` and `Xelement` is that html is not necessarily xml in general.